# ADT emulator fails with "No Space left on device" by 150GB Space

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I just installed the latest ADT `Build: v22.3.0-887826` with Android 4.4.2 and updated the tools and extras in the sdk manager. I have a SSD with 150 GB left and another internal storage HDD with 2xx GB space left. If I create a new device using a device definition of the nexus 7, i get the following error (not only on the nexus 7 prefs.) :

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Nexus7'
NAND: could not write file /tmp/android-zero/emulator-DdOPAF, No space left on device
```

I tried to delete the avd but it changed nothing. I set the dir to `chmod -R 777` but nothing.
I also double checked my $PATH to platform-tools & tools.
I have no idea what is going on. PS. I'm on OS X 10.9 Maverricks and using Phonegap.

---

---

[Edit]

As Sasho discribed:

I changed my existing RamFS to fit the ADT emulator settings RAM.
I had no idea which size my RamFS had.
1. So I decided to delete the folder:

```
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/StartupItems/RamFS
```

2. After a restart (recommend) I used this shell script:
[MoveTemporaryFoldersToRamdisk_MacOSX.sh](https://gist.github.com/pklaus/931579#file-movetemporaryfolderstoramdisk_macosx-sh)  
and changed the size of my `RAMDisk /private/tmp 256` in line 55 to `1024`

Simply create it in your home directory with:

```
cd ~/
sudo vim MoveTemporaryFoldersToRamdisk.sh
chmod 755 MoveTemporaryFoldersToRamdisk_MacOSX.sh
sh MoveTemporaryFoldersToRamdisk_MacOSX.sh
```

After another restart of my system, everything worked fine!
 
If it's still not working for you: check your RAM settings in your emulator and change the size of your RamFS depending on your real hardware RAM and your emulator settings or simply get rid of it like in Sasho's answer.

Comment: I have the same issue.
Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this.
If you have a MAC OS X. You might want to disable RamFS you created.
either:

```
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/StartupItems/RamFS
```

or:

```
sudo chmod -R 000 /System/Library/StartupItems/RamFS
```

The latter to disable it.

Don't forget to restart the MAC after performing one of the above steps ;)

Aparantly the SDK is giving misleading information on which mount the space is not enough...

You could also increase the size of the RamFS but how much RAM do you have?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I nearly gave up... I fixed my question with the right answer for me.